# Use a Column Value from SQL Query in a WHERE Clause?

Tags: sql, mysql, select, where-clause

In mySQL, is it possible to use a column value in a SQL condition ie. a WHERE clause?

**mySQL-Table**

```
|id|name  |valid_from         |valid_to|active|language|color|sub_condition|
|1 |test 1|2019-03-01 05:20:15|null    |1     |en      |red  |language='en'|
|2 |test 2|2019-03-01 05:20:15|null    |1     |de      |blue |color='blue' |
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE active = 1 AND
      valid_from <= NOW() AND
      sub_condition
```

*sub_condition* should be the value from the table.

I want to define more detailed conditions in selected rows.

Comment: Yes, that is "possible". If you need help designing the query, please post what that `sub_condition` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking:

> *Can I do something like eval() in SQL, to evaluate an expression stored in data?*

No, you can't. All of a query's syntax, like expressions, table names, and column names, must be explicit and fixed before the query is prepared. Data values the query reads during execution cannot change the logic of the query.

You can read the data and then depending on how your app interprets that data, run a *second* SQL query with that logic. But you can't have one query that both reads the data and executes the logic during the same query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.
But it depends on what you're looking for.

For example you can  `LIKE`.
And the single quotes can be escaped with a backslash.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE active=1 
  AND valid_from <= NOW()
  AND sub_condition LIKE '%language=\'en\'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use an alias.

```
SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.active=1 AND t.valid_from <= NOW() AND (select * from table where (sub_condition))
```

And the sub_condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use column value as an AND condition to filter results, but you can use column name as AND condition to filter results.

SQL query will consider language='en' in sub_condition column name as a column value and not otherwise.

The appropriate way you can filter results is like this

Example;

$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE active=1 AND valid_from <= NOW() AND lang='eng'");